# AWS server connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple API set on my AWS instance. While I am able to call the api functions from US geographic location, my friend gets a connection refused from from India on the same URL.

I am unable to find out a reason for this. I tried adding the IP (both mine and his) to AWS security group. While AWS responds to all my requests, even if i use a different IP in the same geographical region, none of the IP requests from India work. This is the case even if i have the security settings to All Traffic/Anywhere in AWS.

Any direction in debugging this will prove helpful.

Comment: This is highly likely to be a configuration from your end, either security groups or VPC settings. AWS and their infrastructure would have no reason to block countries like that.

Comment: Today, Airtel had some problems connecting to US hosted sites... I was also not able to connect to aws console and EC2 instance from India. Now it is working fine. Check if your friend was using airtel connection...

Comment: I think it is airtel connection problem. Thanks for this. It works now.